# How can I make my own method into a chainable LINQ method?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have code like this, which builds data to a specific format from an input collection, and appends a checksum value:

```
        var data = input.Aggregate(new List<byte>(), (list, item) =>
        {
            list.Add(item.x);
            list.Add(item.y);
            list.Add(item.bytes.Length);
            list.AddRange(item.bytes);
        });
        data.Add(Checksum(data));
        var bytes = data.ToArray();
```

I interested to make this a single line but I cannot see how I can chain `data` into `Checksum()` which currently has the signature `byte Checksum(IEnumerable<byte> input)`.

I thought I could do something like:

```
        IEnumerable<byte> AddCheckSum(IList<byte> input)
        {
         return input.Add(Checksum(input));
        }

        var data = input.Aggregate(new List<byte>(), (list, item) =>
        {
            list.Add(item.x);
            list.Add(item.y);
            list.Add(item.bytes.Length);
            list.AddRange(item.bytes);
        }).AddChecksum().ToArray();
```

But I can't figure out how. Is it straighforward?

Comment: ["Extension Methods"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) is the droid you are looking for.

Comment: You'd want a signature like `List<byte> AddChecksum(this List<byte> data);`  Or I guess you could go with `IEnumerable<byte> AddChecksum(this IEnumerable<byte> data)`

Comment: I've used them before but how are they used to implement a chainable LINQ method... an extension on _what_?

Comment: I never said it would compile, I said that was the idea I was going along... you're right it needs `List`.

Comment: you need `List<T>`, not `IList<T>`.

Comment: With an `IEnumerable` you can do `return input.Append(Checksum(input));`

Answer (score 2):

I doubt if you want `Aggregate` at all; *Linq* seems to be more compact readable with `SelectMany` and `Concat`:

```
var data = input
  .SelectMany(item => new byte[] {item.x, item.y, item.bytes.Length}.Concat(item.bytes));

var bytes = data
  .Concat(new byte[] {Checksum(data)})
  .ToArray();
```

but I suggest `foreach` solution with explicit `List<byte> data`:

```
List<byte> data = new List<byte>();

foreach (var item in input) {
  data.Add(item.x);
  data.Add(item.y);
  data.Add(item.bytes.Length);
  data.AddRange(item.bytes);
} 

data.Add(Checksum(data));

var bytes = data.ToArray();
```

Finally, if you want to compute the fragment in one go, you can wrap it into an *extension method*:

```
public static class MyInputExtensions {
  public static byte[] ToBytesWithCheckSum(this IEnumerable<MyInput> input) {
    if (null == input)
      throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(input));  

    List<byte> data = new List<byte>();

    foreach (var item in input) {
      data.Add(item.x);
      data.Add(item.y);
      data.Add(item.bytes.Length);
      data.AddRange(item.bytes);
    }      

    data.Add(Checksum(data));

    return data.ToArray(); 
  }
}
```

then you can use `ToBytesWithCheckSum()` as if it's a method of `input` collection:

```
 byte[] bytes = input.ToBytesWithCheckSum();
```

Comment: Isn't your `SelectMany` approach creating a new array for each input element? I'm not sure if that really matters...

Comment: @Mr. Boy: yes, it creates an array in each iteration; that's the very reason I prefer `foreach` solution if there's a chance that `input` is a *large* collection

Answer (score 1):

Use extension method.

```cs
public static class AddChecksumHelpers
{
    public static IEnumerable<byte> AddCheckSum(this IEnumerable<byte> input)
    {
        return input.Concat(new[] { CheckSum(input) });
    }
}
```

Or you could take and return `List<byte>` if you have data in that format and directly return the input list (after calling `.Add(CheckSum(input))`).

Comment: Good point, I was focusing more on the "how to chain calls" and the answer is use "extension method". Arguments and return value would need to be Lists then, and the whole code would be more clear using normal loop, but that's bit outside of what the question asked.

Comment: @huancz Or just change `Add` to `Append` : `return input.Append(CheckSum(input));`.

Comment: For `IEnumerable` you can use `Append` instead of `Add`.

Comment: @DStanley `Concat` doesn't work with a single value it would have to be `return input.Concat(new[] { CheckSum(input) });`

Comment: @juharr Thanks, fixed.